# Validate or parse a string for XML?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, xml

I have a Description textbox on the page. When enter the data in that and submit the page. I will pass that string to XML tag in the XML file.

If user enter any invalid characters in textbox which are not allowed for xml. How to remove or parse them from string? I need to validate string for XML data.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) classes to build the XML then you don't need to worry as they'll do the encoding for you.

Otherwise, if you generating the XML by hand you can use the [SecurityElement.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape%28VS.80%29.aspx) method to encode invalid XML characters

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you are creating the XML. If you are assembling the XML string yourself, there are A LOT of things you should do and take into consideration.

Thus, you should not be doing that (assembling the string yourself).

.NET provides you with abstraction layers so you don't have to deal with that. Example: [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)